# C++ Vector Operations

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Is there any alternative for this? Performing a vector operation in multiples on certain condition?

i want to perform erase vector operation (n-1) times, just deleting only first element in a particular vector on a given if condition.

is it possible to do like this

```
if ( ret.size() == n ){
        (n-1)*order.erase(order.begin());
        (n-1)*quantity.erase(quantity.begin());
        (n-1)*price.erase(price.begin());
 }
```

I am currently doing this

```
if ( ret.size() == 2 ){
        order.erase(order.begin());
        quantity.erase(quantity.begin());
        price.erase(price.begin());
 }
 if ( ret.size() == 3 ){
        order.erase(order.begin());
        order.erase(order.begin());
        quantity.erase(quantity.begin());
        quantity.erase(quantity.begin());
        price.erase(price.begin());
        price.erase(price.begin());
}
```

Comment: You can erase more than one item at a time, if that's what you're asking. Use the erase overload that takes in two iterators. .... Otherwise, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: There are also easier ways to erase all except the last element, if that's what you want.

Comment: Have you considered reversing the storage order? It's far more efficient to keep only the first element than the last, and it can accomplished with `the_vector.resize(1)`.  It also looks like you would benefit from having one vector of structs instead of three vectors.
.

Comment: @churill what's the syntax for that?

Comment: @Puniith: See my updated answer. (And note how your *actual* problem -- how to remove all but the last element of that vector -- was hidden from us because you did not provide a [mcve], so we had to guess what `ret.size()` actually was.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order.erase( order.begin(), order.begin() + ( ret.size() - 1 ) );
```

Needs prior checking of `ret.size()` vs. `order.size()` of course, but it seems your code can assert that from context.

That being said, when you are repeatedly erasing from the beginning of your vectors, perhaps your vectors are sorted the wrong way, or you might be better off with [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), performance-wise.

---

**Edit:** From the comments, it appears that your *actual* problem is "how to remove all but the last element of a vector". There are a number of ways to do this, like

```
// actually erasing all but the last
order.erase( order.begin(), order.end() - 1 );
```

...or...

```
// creating a new vector with the last element of the old
order = vector< ... >{ order.back() };
```

(The elipsis here standing for the type of your `order` vector, not the actual elipsis -- you will have to fill in that part.)

Comment: Also, the comment by @molbdnilo: Looks as if you should have a vector of structs, not three individual vectors.